# Algorithm Optimisation in Node, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm

Given the following json array

`const groups=[{ id:1, parent:null, groupName:'Others', maxScore:3},
    {id:2, parent:null, groupName: 'Group 1', maxScore:0},
    {id:3, parent:2, groupName:'Others, maxScore:2},
    {id:4, parent:2, groupName:'Sub Group 1', maxScore:1}];`

What would be a more performance oriented approach to sum maxScores within **parents** ? 
It looks like a tree structure, but nodes don't have references to their children.

Im trying a map.reduce approach right now

```
function addMaxScoreToGroups(groups) {
    return groups.map((group) => {
      const newGroup = group;
      if (group.parent === null && group.name !== 'Others') {
        const children = groups.filter(elem => elem.parent === group.id);
          if (children) {
            newGroup.maxScore = children.map(x => x.maxScore)
           .reduce((value, acum) => value + acum);
          }
      }
      return newGroup;
    });
}
```

Expected result would be

`const groups=[{ id:1, parent:null, groupName:'Others', maxScore:3},
    {id:2, parent:null, groupName: 'Group 1', maxScore:0,maxPosibleScore:3},
    {id:3, parent:2, groupName:'Others, maxScore:2},
    {id:4, parent:2, groupName:'Sub Group 1', maxScore:1}];`

Comment: Questions asking for **The Best....** are highly subjective. What performs **best** for one might not for another.  You can use jsPerf or similar sites/tools to test performance on approaches/solution that work/give the correct results and use what fits your scenario best. - If you don't have a working solution yet, then re-phrase the question to focus on that instead.

Comment: It is working actually, but I think it can be optimized in terms of how many times i need to map.reduce to get the correct result.

Comment: If your code is working and you are looking for optimization https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might get you better answers as those type of questions are usually off topic on Stackoverflow. See What Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). For each object create a new entry (or update existing one in case of parent) by cloning the object using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) (or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

If the object has a parent, create the parent if it doesn't exist, and add/update the `maxPossibleScore`.

Convert back to array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
const groups=[{ id:1, parent:null, groupName:'Others', maxScore:3}, {id:3, parent:2, groupName:'Others', maxScore:2}, {id:4, parent:2, groupName:'Sub Group 1', maxScore:1}, {id:2, parent:null, groupName: 'Group 1', maxScore:5}];
    
const ms = 'maxScore';
const mps = 'maxPossibleScore';
const result = Object.values(groups.reduce((r, o) => {
  // clone
  const c = { ...o };
  
  // if current parent initalized before, update maxPossibleScore
  if(!o.parent && r[o.id]) c[mps] = r[o.id][mps] + c[ms];
  
  r[o.id] = c;
  
  if(o.parent) {
    // if parent doesn't exist init
    r[o.parent] = r[o.parent] || {};
    // if parent.maxPossibleScore doesn't exist init it
    if(!(mps in r[o.parent])) {
      r[o.parent][mps] = r[o.parent][ms] || 0;
    }
    
    r[o.parent][mps] += o[ms];
  }
  
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Probably @nope :)

Comment: Why? OP did ask for better performing code, why would your perform better than OPs existing code and how are you determining that? jsPerf or similar?

Comment: Big O notation - O(n) vs. at least O(n^2) (current solution). Since we're I'm using reduce, which invokes callback functions, it's less performant than a simple for loop.

Comment: @OriDrori, its not wokring :( If I just have one parent=null, its maxPosibleScore stays 0

Comment: Should be fixed now. If not, add a test case in the comments.